# Dovecot and lz4: unknown handler

Tags: dovecot, ubuntu-14.04, maildir

I'm trying to compress my incoming Maildir-formatted mail.  My server is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`:

`mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib`

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-plugin.conf`:

`plugin {
    zlib_save_level = 9
    zlib_save = lz4
  }`

The dovecot log says:

**`Error: zlib_save: Unknown handler: lz4`**

I have installed the following packages in an attempt to remedy this:

`apt-get install liblz4-1 liblz1 liblz4-dev liblz4-tool liblz-dev lzma libwrap0`

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot added support for lz4 compression in v2.2.11.  Ubuntu 14.04's version is v2.2.9.

https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot-news/2014-February/000269.html

Comment: (At least maybe now search engines with have a useful result for that error message.)